# Image names are not displaying in the jList

Tags: image, swing, netbeans-7, jlist

My code is given below.I want to display all the image names into the jList from a folder.But the following code displays the names in the output screen not in the jList.Please help to solve this

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {     
String path = "C:\\Users\\Dell\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\pasword2\\src\\images\\";


 File folder = new File(path);
    File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();
    DefaultListModel listModel = new DefaultListModel();
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < listOfFiles.length; i++)
    {
        System.out.println("check path"+listOfFiles[i]);
        String name = listOfFiles[i].toString();
        // load only JPEGs
        if ( name.endsWith("jpg")||name.endsWith("bmp") ) {
            try
            {
            ImageIcon ii = new ImageIcon(ImageIO.read(listOfFiles[i]));
            listModel.add(count++, ii);
            }
            catch(IOException e){}
        }
    }
    jList1.setModel(listModel);
}
```

Comment: Don't swallow your exception. Put something meaningful like `ex.printStackTrace()` so you know when/what exception is thrown, if one is

Comment: I tried,but it doesnt shows any error

Comment: @  peeskillet:I checked the list.listOfFiles[] contain all the names.Then what is the problem?

Comment: Put an SOP(name) to see what it prints out. Let me know

Comment: @peeskillet: C:\Users\Dell\Documents\NetBeansProjects\pasword2\src\images\_MG_4082.JPG

Comment: @peeskillet:sir are you checked it?

Comment: Sorry, I think I misread your question. So do you want the file name AND the image to show, or just the file name?

Comment: got it sir.It was my mistake ,images are in .JPG and now got the file name as listOfFiles[i].getName()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want the file name only to appear in the list, but you're adding the image instead. So instead of

```
try{
    ImageIcon ii = new ImageIcon(ImageIO.read(listOfFiles[i]));
    listModel.add(count++, ii);
}
catch(IOException e){}
```

Just do

```
listModel.add(count++, listOfFiles[i].getName());
```

If you want to store the ImageIcon and the file name into one object, you can create a wrapper class. Something like

```
public class NamedImageIcon {
    private String imageName;
    private ImageIcon icon;

    public NamedImageIcon(ImagIcon icon, String imageName) {
        this.icon = icon;
        this.imageName = imageName;
    }

    // getters and setters

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return imageName;
    }
}
```

No when you're looping you can create a wrapper for the name and for the image. You can then add instances of `NamedImageIcon` to the `DefaultListModel`. And since you override the toString(), the only thing that will appear in the list is the name. So when you select the name from the list, you will have direct access the corresponding image